# Can roslaunch setup rxconsole filters?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have setup a launch file that starts rxconsole, rxplot, ros_vrpn_client, rviz, and my own custom node. As it sits rxconsole starts up showing info items only. I would like it to start up showing debug message and preferably only a subset of them. Does it support setting filters from the command line or via the param tag in a roslaunch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32250/can-roslaunch-setup-rxconsole-filters?/) by [Dustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1938/dustin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2012-04-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe so.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1